# How to Identify 32 bit processes

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit

I am writing an C# plug-in for an auditing application, which need to fetch a list of 32 bit applications running inside a 64-bit OS. I got stuck up at this point on how to identify a 32-bit process.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows API call to determine if a process is running under 32bit emulation on a 64bit OS.

Here is the [pinvoke link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.iswow64process)

**Update**: I benchmarked this a little bit, with the following results:

- Enumerating all the processes with `Process.GetProcesses()` takes the majority of the time with approx. 12ms on my laptop having 93 processes running
- Obtaining the handle and executing the `IsWow64Process` call took approx. 0.1ms per process on the same laptop.
- Obtaining all the processes with WMI took approx. 520ms on the same laptop (also 93 processes running).

Basically: If you can cope with the fact that the process might go away after you obtained the list and before you managed to query it then using the pinvoke way seems faster and snappier to me than using WMI. Although WMI might be the less intrusive way (from a process standpoint of view).

Comment: This method is better, but is subject to race conditions, since opening a handle to every process is not particularly snappy and the process could die while he tries to query it. WMI already has the info he needs, and he doesn't have to worry about the nuances of getting a correct process list

Comment: Well, at least the snappy does not hold quite true.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxtoolsdev/thread/491ea0b3-3e5b-4fa2-a2c3-2f1e485aed0c/.

I think it's possible with WMI.

Comment: What you *shouldn't* do, is do any of the other solutions mentioned in that thread - stick with the WMI approach, it's the most sane solution by far!

Comment: Paul - why is WMI a superior solution to  PInvoking kernel32.dll to get the WoW64 state for any process handle?